# Runtime error (warning?): Failed to create 0x88 image slot, does anybody have a clue?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, storyboard, asset-catalog

I'm writing an app in Storyboard/Swift (XCode 14.2). When I run the app on my iPhone (14 pro 16.3.1) or on an iPhone simulator (16.2) no error is given. But when I test my app in an iPad simulator (tried the pro, air and normal):

> [API] Failed to create 0x88 image slot (alpha=1 wide=0) (client=0x29bd01dc) [0x5 (os/kern) failure]

I make use of an UICollectionView as a menu and when I press the corresponding tile/button the error is printed in the debug area. The app is not interrupted and seems working fine.

I tried to Google the problem and search StackOverflow, but it doesn't give me enough clues about what to do. Google/Stack has practically no results.

I'm pretty new to Swift. I make use of a single size app icon (1024pt), instead of all those adapted ones. Every image is given in Universal mode, 1x,2x and 3x. (Made with Asset Catalog Creator Pro)

Can anybody point me to my mistake?

Comment: something is missing or incorrect in your assets. Did you provide all app icon sizes for example?

Comment: Getting same issue all of a sudden on Ipad sims only. For me the warning was dismissed when I removed  .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()) from my code (used to get rid of splitView on Ipad). Not sure of a workaround just yet.

Comment: At least it seems not a problem for executing. But it’s annoying.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same runtime error with NavigationStack though Op uses Storyboard. I wrote my reason to get this error, so whoever get this may get help from my cause;

I've placed a new view to the beginning and then forgot to erase NavigationStack from the old first view ( in my case it was a displaying a Tabview). So, one navigation stack inside the other was the problem.

I hope this helps others. I've just spend hours to find the cause.

In my personal experiences, Swift compiler is not a mature compiler to provide helpful causes on SwiftIU.

Comment: @HangarRash I've got the same runtime error. It is not a compile time error.

Comment: OK but the last line of your answer is talking about the compiler. The compiler isn't involved in runtime issues.

Comment: @HangarRash I'd stoned the compiler not finding the mistake and not generating the correct issue on the runtime. I've seen many problems of the compiler during my work and on the internet. Interestingly, It was not displaying the problem on IPhone pro 14, however, the results were the same.

Comment: I am seeing this same error at runtime in my code.  It is not clear to me at all why it is showing.  I do not have navigationViewStyle in my code at all.  I am not using Storyboards at all..

Comment: @MichaelRowe If you find the cause, post it as an answer, I'll up vote.